# Structuring nested math functions in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I am attempting to set up in Handlebars a value that should come out as two separate division math statements added together, then added to another value.

The overall pseudocode of it would be this: `result + (var1 divided by 10) + (var2 divided by 100)`

My attempt at Handlebars code for it is this: `{{plus result (divide var1 10) plus (divide var2 100)}}`

How can I adjust the structure of these statements to get these nested math functions to work? Can it work with 3 statements being added together instead of 2 that the `plus` helper is built around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it isn't clear what `result` is.

Second, this sort of logic really doesn't belong in a template. You would be better to do you these math operations prior to sending data to your template function.

However, it would be possible to call your helpers in a nested fashion, but you would need to put each helper call in its own set of parens.

The result would be:

```
{{plus result (plus (divide var1 10) (divide var2 100))}}
```

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile('{{plus result (plus (divide var1 10) (divide var2 100))}}');

Handlebars.registerHelper('divide', function (a, b) {
  return a / b;
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('plus', function (a, b) {
  return a + b;
});

const output = template({
  result: 5,
  var1: 100,
  var2: 2000
});

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.8/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```